# Git: How to integrate selected files from another repo into branches in main repo?

Tags: git

Here's the setup:

We have a documentation team, who works in their own git repository.

In the main product repository we have master and beta branches, beta was branched from master at merge ID 12345.

Periodically the doc team needs to integrate the resulting ZIP with the latest documentation (not all the doc files, just that ZIP) into both master and beta branches of the main product repository.

What's the best workflow for this? I'm afraid if the doc person just manually updates the documentation ZIP on both branches, there would be problems when merging other changes between master and beta.

Thank you!

Comment: So far we did the following:
`git checkout -b doc-branch 12345`
Then the writer manually copies the latest ZIP into the doc-branch, then merges doc-branch into master and beta. Wondering if it was possible to do this without the doc-branch branch.

Answer (score 3):

how about using `git submodule`? the documentation repo could be added a submodule in your main product repo.

Comment: to the remote main repo or the doc writer's clone of the main repo? What if the doc repo is just local to the doc writer's machine (don't know if this is really the case)